# How to keep angular PWA running in doze mode

Tags: angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

We are developing an angular PWA application that subscribes to some data changes from a [lightStreamer Server](https://lightstreamer.com/) and shows some notifications to user . As you know, PWAs are alternative for native apps, so we expect that when mobile goes to doze mode, our application continues to doing it's job as before and alarms notification when some conditions being established.
Is it possible to handle this in angular framework or Service Workers?

Comment: Notifications (ONLY if enabled by the user) still work for a PWA that is closed. What have you tested and what errors (if any) have you seen or what is not working as expected? the more details the better.

Comment: @Mathias thank you for your answer. my question is not about push notifications. I want to keep my application running to check some conditions being established, then I alert by custom notification.

Comment: What type of conditions? Happening locally or on your server?

Comment: I doubtful this is something you'll be able to manage with a web app.

Comment: As I said before, we subscribe to a Light Streamer Server. this server pushes data to our application. conditions are applying to this data. so we need application running always to check it.

Comment: @abraham I hoped i could find some solution.

Comment: I think you need to reconsider using push Notifications.  These will work, even if your program is not running.  I've never heard of "doze" mode...  Perhaps you can convert your Light Stream to push, or optionally send your user a push, then retrieve all the Light Stream messages you want in the notification call-back.

Comment: [Doze is an proprietary Android API](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby) and I think the best optimization for it will have to be a native app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highly inefficient but it you have to: - [WakeLock](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/12/wakelock)

Support is a bit of a problem at the moment :-(

Alternatively, if you PUSH a "data updated" notification to your ServiceWorker it can foreground or activate your Web App.